# How to execute code every time url changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making an ajax site. How would I go about executing some javascript every time the url changes. Say when "/#page/aboutus/" changes to "/#page/news/".

I want users to be able to bookmark ajax-pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be easier to do a different way, for example a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event handler:

```
$("a").live('click', function() {
  //do something with this.hash
});
```

But, if you do indeed need to trigger with `location.hash` changes, you can use the [`onhashchange` plugin for this](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) (at least until it's supported natively in *every* browser).

For example:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){
  //do something with location.hash here
});
```

Comment: A check for window.location.hash on page load and one event handler should take care of my problem. Thanks.